# In PHP, how do you calculate the sun's azimuth?

Tags: php

I know how to use the sun info function to get some info about the sun, but it doesn't offer a way to get the azimuth for a given date/time/location. Specifically, I want to get the azimuth at sunset to display in a graph where I show the length of day and sunrise/sunset.

I've seen at least one answer that partially applies, but it's a long and complicated function that calculates a whole lot of things I don't need. Since I'll need to calculate the azimuth for 365 days, I think this will add a lot of processor load and time in generating the chart.

I'm hoping for a simpler formula that will provide just the azimuth for a lat/long and timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tiny PHP library called SunCalc. SunCalc is a tiny PHP library for calculating sun position, sunlight phases (times for sunrise, sunset, dusk, etc.)

Here you can find the lib and exemples : [Source](https://github.com/gregseth/suncalc-php)